# Why should ViewState be encrypted when post data is not?

Tags: asp.net

Exactly that. I don't understand it quite.

ViewState encryption is provided in order to protect user-data privacy, but what is the point of setting ViewState to be encrypted if, e.g., using http (not https) posted form data is clearly visible for an interceptor from the http messsage body?

Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Where did you get this information? Can you post a link?

Comment: Which one? That view state encryption could be set? On many places,  like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479501.aspx .
If you're asking about post-data not being encrypted in a regular http, isn't it like that?

Actually, not in a http header, but the body - I just corrected that.

Answer (score 1):

The point of ViewState encryption is to ensure the data is not *tampered* with, it's not about protecting it from being viewed. From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> By creating a hash value, the ASP.NET page framework can test whether the view state data has been tampered with. But view state data can still be viewed, and can potentially be intercepted and read by malicious users.
>   ... While MAC encoding helps prevent tampering with view state data, it does not prevent users from viewing the data.

**Update**

My initial comment may appear a little misleading - you *can* protect viewing of the ViewState by using encryption, however, this **does not** encrypt the actual `POST` data (which was the point I was getting at).

Comment: Are you suggesting ViewState is not encrypted but only a hash control value is added next to it so ASP.NET engine could check on a postback if someone has tampered with it?

It's logical to add hash checksums to protect from the situation as HackedByChinese described above, but on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479501.aspx they are talking about encryption all the time. I was in doubt about encryption not hash checksums.

Comment: @Срба The cited article states "To reduce the chance of someone intercepting the information stored in the ViewState".  I agree that is a misleading statement, since if you were worried about interception, you would encrypt the entire connection through HTTPS.  I think the ViewState encryption feature is better used as an additional layer to prevent tampering, not interception.

Comment: Ok, to conclude: when we say ViewState encryption, we talk about adding a hash checksum field or something similar, to ensure from tampering, not about the whole data encryption ?

Comment: The purpose of the ViewState is to persist **control-state** (not post information). The ViewState *does* encrypt the data, but only during post-back. The `POST` data is completely separate you would need to use SSL if you wanted that encrypted as well.

Comment: Your very first sentence is simply wrong, the MAC is to prevent tampering, viewstate encryption is to prevent a user from viewing the viewstate.

Comment: @user145400 you clearly didn't read my answer in full, I mentioned at the bottom that the view state *can* be used to prevent viewing of it and I agree the statement appears to be misleading (hence why I added edited it). I was trying to highlight the difference between the view state & post data and why they are not related. There was obviously a bit of confusion in the answer based on how I worded it so I might update when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Since ViewState is used to synthesize statefulness in a stateless environment, it can contain information used internally by the pages to track the state of a page as a user interacts with it.

Therefore, it could potentially be used to extract, modify, or malform view state information to affect how the page works. In particular, it prevents "one-click attacks" (where complete state is prebuilt and posted in one shot). Post data is not encrypted (other than by transport, if you use SSL) because A) there isn't really a mechanism for this in HTTP or HTML and B) it's a single trip, where the client originates the data anyways.

If you don't use ViewState at all (good for you!), or are confident it can't be used to maliciously manipulate or extract user info, then don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep sensitive data in view state you may want it to be encrypted. By default view state is not encrypted unless a control on the page requests encryption.